# Proof: For all real numbers $x$, If $x^2 - 5x + 4 \geq 0$, then either $x ≤ 1$ or $x ≥ 4$.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I need some help in proving the following statement:
$x$, If $x^2 - 5x + 4 \geq 0$, then either $x ≤ 1$ or $x ≥ 4$.
It would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide me a generic proof! I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around this one. Thanks!
Edit: I've got to the point where $(x-4)(x-1) \geq 0$ and thus have two cases to prove. I don't know how to prove the two cases!

Comment: well before giving a generic proof, can you see why this is true by sketching f(x)=x^2-5x+4

Comment: A very popular question recently! I would count $3$ cases.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x^2-5x+4 = (x-4)(x-1)$.

Hint-2: Suppose the real numbers $a,b$ satisfy $ab \geq 0$. Show that either $a\geq 0,\,b\geq 0$ or $a\leq 0,\,b\leq 0$.

Comment: I got to the stage and thus have two cases to prove. I don't know what to do after those two cases, could you please hint me on?

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to use this too

$∀a∈R,∀b∈R,[(ab≥0)⟷(((a≥0)∧(b≥0))∨((a≤0)∧(b≤0)))].$

Comment: I'm getting $0 \geq 0$

Comment: also me and my partner are still working on this question, but we don't know how to format it properly.  We think we know the proof, or at least the general proof idea.

Comment: @wonggr all that says is a nice reminder that both $a$ and $b$ need to be positive $\vee$ negative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try sketching the curve and look at where the curve is above the $x$-axis. If you don't want to sketch the curve, just note that the curve intersects the $x$-axis when $x^2-5x+4=(x-4)(x-1)=0$.

So why do you think we need $x\leq 1$ and $x\geq4$?

Comment: those are the parts where the graph is negative..

Comment: Are you sure? Is the curve above or below the $x$-axis?

Answer (score 1):

ok after your edit let me add something

$(x-1)(x-4)\ge0$

so either both the brackets are both positive or both negative for the inequality to occur and if equality occurs, one of the brackets=0.

for the case where both brackets are positive we get:

$x>1$, $x>4$ which boils down to $x>4$ as we want BOTH brackets to be positive

similarly for the case where both the brackets are negative, we get $x<1$.

Add in the third case of equality and you should get the desired result.